# which are positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that $A,B$ are positive definite matrix, are they also PD?

1. $A+B$
2. $AB$
3. $A^2 +I$
4. $ABA^{*}$

$x^TAx>0, x^TBx>0$ so $1$, is correct, could you tell me about the 2, 3,4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mex

in 4. we can argue as follows:

$\langle x, ABA^* x\rangle = \langle A^*x, BA^* x\rangle = 
\langle B^*A^*x, A^* x\rangle = \langle B Ax, A x\rangle 
= \langle B y,  y\rangle >0 $,
where $y=Ax$ and in the two last equalities we use that positive matrix are self-adjoint and since they do not have $0$ 
as eigenvalue then $Ay\neq 0$.

for 3. the argument is similar.

Comment: @Leonardo, thank you very much

Comment: @Mex Leandro :)

Comment: Leandro!!! for (3) $\langle x,(A^2+I)x \langle=\langle x,A^2x \langle +\langle x,x\langle= \langle Ax,Ax \langle+ \langle x,x \langle>0$ right?

Comment: Yes and worth to mention that in the definition of positivity we only have to verify the inequality for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: positive definite matrices are self adjoint?could you tell me how?

Comment: @Tojamaru : Positive definite matrices are symmetric (which is same as self adjoint for real matrix) but for complex matric I am not sure how :O