# which of the followings are positive definite:

Tags: linear-algebra

**(CSIR-UGC NET Mathematical Sciences-2011)**

> Suppose $A,B$ are $n \times n$ positive definite. Then which of the followings are positive definite:
>
> 1. $A+B$
> 2. $ABA^{*}$
> 3. $A^2+I$
> 4. $AB$

Comment: Maybe tell us your definition of positive definitenes and where you're stuck. It's probably not the best idea for us to solve the problem for you when it is most likely an immediate application of the definition.

Comment: $A$ is positive definite $\iff X^tAX>0~\forall~X$ (column vector), that's what I know. Using it I can see that $1$ is true. But what about the others?

Comment: What can you say about the nullspace of a positive definite matrix? Use this to solve 2 and 3. As for 4, $AB$ will not necessarily be symmetric, and you can try and look at the $2\times 2$ case to find counterexamples.

Comment: Are you sure that in your definition of positive definiteness, you *only* require that $x^TAx>0$ for all $x\ne0$, but not that $A$ is symmetric? The answer of (3) depends on whether symmetry of $A$ is required.

Comment: Do studying positive definiteness using the concept of inner product help it to solve easily?

Comment: I've seen it's application here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158559/which-are-positive-definite-matrix?rq=1 which I didn't understand. Could anyone suggest any **short** lecture note/material?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/158559)

Comment: @robjohn: Yep I noticed that later.

Comment: @SritiMallick In general product need not be positive definite because  because for Hermitian $A$ and $B$, $(AB)^{∗}=AB$ if and only if A and B commute.  $ABA$ can be positive definite.

Comment: @robjohn: Could you tell me whether the concept of inner product help me anyhow?

Comment: @SritiMallick: since $M$ is positive definite when $\langle x,Mx\rangle\gt0$ for all $x\ne0$, I would say that inner products are key.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer:**
Your complete answer can be given by combining these two links

[link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158559/which-are-positive-definite-matrix)

[link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66520/if-a-and-b-are-positive-definite-matrices-is-ab-positive-definite)

and possible my partial answer

If $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are positive definite then $x^t A x > 0$, $x^t B x > 0$, 
$\forall x \neq 0  $. This implies that $x^t (A + B)x = x^t A x+ x^t B x > 0$. Hence sum of two positive definite matrices positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

case #4 has a simple counterexample (if $A$ is not necessarily symmetric or Hermit):

$A = B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
 -1&1 
\end{pmatrix}$,

$x = (0, 1)$.

Since $z^{T}Az= z_1^2+z_2^2 ,A$ is positive defined; however

x<sup>T</sup>ABx = xTAAx = 0